# How to add Annotations /pins in MapBox using RMAnnotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, mapbox

For customized map view I downloaded MapBox example from github using the following git clone --recursive

[**MapBox iOS Example**](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-example)

I do all cloning steps and exicutes succesufully,

Now i need to display some Annotations pins for some locations, i have addresses.

can any one help me out how to achieve this

[image]

Comment: can you post code of what you have managed to do so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you have addresses, look into Apple's `CLGeocoder` to geocode them into locations, which you can then set as each `RMAnnotation` object's `coordinate`.